# VBA MACRO Make Variable Range

Tags: vba, excel

I really struggled in making this work.

I have below line of code:

```
 ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Diags").Range("$A1:$Y50000")
```

I am successful if I will convert the last number after $Y as below:

```
 ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Diags").Range("$A1:$Y" & MyVariable)
```

, but how to integrate also a variable after $A? I tried below but does not work..

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Diags").Range("$A1"& MyVariable2":$Y" & MyVariable1)
```

Appreciate your help.
Thanks, Brandon

Comment: I want to make my range a variable instead of fix size 
for example Range(A1:A20).Value    I need to create a variable to hold the value of 1 and 20...if you don't get it how come.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an `&` behind `MyVariable2`, and you have an extra `1` behind `$A`. Try

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Diags").Range("$A" & MyVariable2 & ":$Y" & MyVariable1)
```

Comment: I used your suggestion as below:

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim MyVariable2 As Integer
Dim MyVariable1 As Integer

MyVariable2 = 1
MyVariable1 = 1

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RSEMappingControl").Range("$A" & MyVariable2 & ":$Y" & MyVariable1).Value = "test"

End Sub

and it works very well! thanks!